# Classic rule fishing: Has or had

Tags: grammar, tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

I have a feeling both tenses are relevant here, but need some guidance if possible.

```
“He knew how to use the machine because he has/had used it before.”
```

Please correct me if I am wrong, we should be using *`had`* over *`has`*,

because there is a connection between two activities that happened in the past, where the first causes the other to happen.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What do you mean by "rule fishing"?

Comment: should have titled it as Grammar fishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite right.

He **knew...** because he **had** used it before.

After He **knows...** you would need ...because he **has** used it before.